# Using Liquid to display different .js embeds depending on page URL

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to get a Shopify collection page to display different .js embeds on a specific part of the page, depending on the URL of the current page.

Can this be done using `{% if page.url == %}` if so, how would I have variants of page URLs and specific embed codes?

The page URL looks like this:

`https://www.example.com/collections/technology/technology-connected-home`

The embed code looks like this:

````
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apps.example.com/app/js/18218989163.js"></script>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Shopify store has different types of pages: index (aka home), product, collection, page, blog, article, and cart. Here is the [full list](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/request#request-page_type) of page types.

So, this `page.url` will only work on a page object of type `page` for all other types you need to use the proper page object to get the `url`:

- `collection.url`
- `product.url`
- etc...

In your case I'd suggest using `case/when`, add your logic in a snippet and `render` it in `theme.liquid`.

Here is an example:

```
{% if request.page_type == 'page' %}
  {% case page.url %}
    {% when '/pages/about-us' %}
      {{ 'pages__about-us.js' | script_tag }}
    {% when '/pages/contact-us' %}
      {{ 'pages__contact-us.js' | script_tag }}
    {% else %}
      {{ 'pages__generic.js' | script_tag }}
  {% endcase %}
{% endif %}
```

[ref](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/tags/control-flow-tags#case-when)

You gonna have to check for `request.page_type` before creating your `case/when` or another approach would be to check the type at the top of the snippet, like:

```
{% comment %} Set page object type {% endcomment %}
{% case request.page_type %}
  {% when 'page' %}
    {% assign page_object = page %}
  {% when 'collection' %}
    {% assign page_object = collection %}
  {% when 'product' %}
    {% assign page_object = product %}
{% endcase %}

{% comment %} Load JS based on page URL{% endcomment %}
{% case page_object.url %}
  {% when '/pages/about-us' %}
    {{ 'pages__about-us.js' | script_tag }}
  {% when '/pages/contact-us' %}
    {{ 'pages__contact-us.js' | script_tag }}
  {% else %}
    {{ 'pages__generic.js' | script_tag }}
{% endcase %}
```

This isn't a bulletproof solution, however it should be enough for you to build on top of it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using page.handle and identifying the handle. I do not believe page.url will do what you need

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this as handle can never be changed.

```
{% case page.handle %}
    {% when 'about-us' %}
      {{ 'pages_about-us.js' | script_tag }}
    {% when 'contact-us' %}
      {{ 'pages_contact-us.js' | script_tag }}
    {% else %}
      {{ 'pages_generic.js' | script_tag }}
  {% endcase %}
```